# I am trying to Redirecting page to the specific tab (slide tab) by using navigateToSObject but it is not working in Aura

Tags: javascript, salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities, aura-framework

I am trying to redirect into specific slide Tab in record page, we can simply achieve this by using workspace API but since workspace api is not supported in the Apps like sales and service etc, I am using navigation to Sobject, here's a sample code that I'm using..
`

```
toDetail : function(component, event, helper) {
        console.log('changeSubtab');
        //get record id from url
        var url = window.location.href;
        var recordId = url.substring(0, url.lastIndexOf('/'));
        recordId = recordId.substring(recordId.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        console.log('recordId: ' + recordId);

        //using navigation event to change subtab
        var navEvt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
        navEvt.setParams({
            "recordId": recordId,
            "slideDevName": "related"
        });
        navEvt.fire();
        console.log('navEvt fired', navEvt);
    },
```

`

[image]

I am basically trying to redirecting it to the related tab but everytime it is redirecting to the default tab Activity, I have also added the line in the .cmp file
`

```
    <aura:dependency resource="markup://force:navigateToSObject" type="EVENT"/>
```

`